# Update existing object values using the setter method

Tags: javascript, object, setter

I have an object with the setter method *model*:

```
var obj = {
   set model(object) {
   //method's logic
   }
}
```

I update the obj with the values:

```
obj = {x:10, y: 20, p: 15};
```

Now the object looks like:

```
obj = {
  x:10, 
  y: 20, 
  p: 15
  set model(object){
  //method logic
  }
  };
```

Please give me a hint how to use the setter method to *update* existing values of the object and process some math operations.
For example, I call the setter method and pass the values:

```
obj.model = { x: { value: 33, operation: '*' },
z: { value: 75, operation: '+' }, 
p: { value: 4, operation: '%' } };
```

In the result, it should return:

```
console.log(obj); // -> {x:330, y: 20, z: 75, p: 3}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is another way to handle this.

```js
var obj = {
   set model(object) {
      Object.keys(object).forEach(key => { 
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' || typeof object[key] !== 'object') {
          obj[key] = typeof object[key] === 'object' 
            ? object[key].value 
            : object[key];
        } else {
          obj[key] = eval(obj[key] + object[key].operation + object[key].value);
        }
      });
   }
}

obj.model = {x:10, y: 20, p: 15};

obj.model = { x: { value: 33, operation: '*' },
z: { value: 75, operation: '+' }, 
p: { value: 4, operation: '%' } };

// Adding new value(s)
obj.model = { a: 123 };

console.log(obj); // -> {x:330, y: 20, z: 75, p: 3}
```

Comment: Hello :) In case I want to assign new values to the obj directly, how it could be done?

Comment: You would just add the new value to your `obj.model` object, like in your example for `z`. updated my answer with a working example...

Comment: This code produces `"model": undefined` in `obj` - I'm pretty sure that wasn't the intention.

Comment: Also, what's "another way to handle this" about this answer? I explained that the assignment should happen to `obj.model`, not to `obj` directly and that's exactly what you did...

Comment: @segFault thanks, I believe it would not work for me to do the math operations, but you've gave me a great hint.:D I will dig it deeper. P.S. I'm female ;)

Comment: @КаринаБариноваS sorry about that! okay no problem

Answer (score 0):

`obj = {x:10, y: 20, p: 15};` is not "passing" arguments to an object - this is assignment to `obj` itself (you're overriding the former definition of `obj`)!

try instead (exactly like you're doing a few lines below):

```
obj.model = {x:10, y: 20, p: 15};
```

Comment: Hello, I know, it is what should be done to override the definition of obj. Next step is to use the model method to update those values. I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @КаринаБаринова from your comment it sounds that you didn't understand the answer. Please re-read it. Assigning new values to the obj directly will override obj and it will no longer point to an object with `model` property.

Comment: I see, this is exactly what my teacher asked to do, will check if it is some kind of misunderstanding